# Close MSI from Custom Action

Tags: wix

I have created a custom action which is executed in InstallUISequence to elevate privileges. The code checks if the privileges are not there, it starts a new process elevated for the same MSI.

```cs
public static ActionResult ElevateInstaller(Session session)
{
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    bool hasAdministrativeRight = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

    if (!hasAdministrativeRight)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.Verb = "runas";
        processInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
        processInfo.Arguments = "/i \"" + session["OriginalDatabase"] + "\"";

        try
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(processInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }

            return ActionResult.SkipRemainingActions;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {          
           return ActionResult.UserExit;
        }
    }         
    else
    {
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This CA works fine to start a elevated MSI. However, after the elevated MSI finishes execution, the Main MSI shows the summary dialog. Is there a way I can skip it and close the MSI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've gotten your [Custom Action Return Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368072.aspx) to do almost exactly what you want. However it still results in one of the termination flags of the [InstallUISequence Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369543.aspx) being executed. You have to come up with a way to prevent it from showing the Dialog in this case; perhaps by supplying a condition just for this case.

Comment: This worked fine for me. I created a property with a default value of 0 in the wix code, I am updating this property when the CA elevates privileges and starts a new MSI. Updated the InstallUISequence. The summary dialog is only displayed if the value of the Property is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to deal with this in the UI is to provide a custom dialog (or at least an information dialog) that shows up with only the Cancel button enabled so the user cannot do a Next to advance the installation. You'd do this by setting a property that causes the custom dialog to be shown. In other words it's the same as any other situation in which the install cannot go on - disable the Next button and leave only Cancel enabled.

I don't know what you mean by "summary dialog".

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phil!